# Eclipse and Flex Plugin

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse - Helios and it is working perfectly.  I am having a little trouble understanding the Flex functionality with Eclipse. Is it possible to download a Flex plugin or whatever it is called free of charge to develop and compile mxml and actionscipt files without having to purchase FlexBuilder 3 or 4 at a price of $600. I am under the impression that Eclipse is a free download and and Flexsdk is a free download.  Can't they be put together into one tool?  I cant afford the $600.

JM

Answer (score 1):

The Flex SDK (command line, ant tools, etc) are free.  But the Eclipse plugin, aka Flash Builder, is commercial and $300 (or free for students, educators, and unemployed folks).  With only the Flex SDK you need to manually compile and debug apps using the command line tools.

Comment: I dont mind using the Flex SDK and compiling manually, however, I have been getting a "cannot find a JVM" error every time I try to compile a mxml file from the command prompt. I have tried everything on earth to try to get it to work. The thing about it is that it was working a t one time. I know I have a JRE installed because my other Java applications work. It is really driving me crazy.

JM

Comment: Make sure you have the Sun JDK 6 installed and that when you type "java" it runs the java from that JDK.  Also you probably need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Jerry, type java --version to verify Java is working correctly. There's more than one way to start a Java app but I'd guess your other Java apps are doing something different.