# Flex sdk is not accessible in eclipce

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin

I have installed eclipce and I want to work with flex.I found some site (http://blog.ickydime.com/2009/01/flash-10-in-flex-3-how-to-install-sdk.html) where somebody said that we need to install flex sdk. And than they said that we need to open window->preferences and on left side select 'Flex'. But I don't have 'Flex' item here... What is wrong? I also installed Flash Builder trial, but it does not make any sence... Please help me....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376344/eclipse-and-flex-plugin

Answer (score 2):

In order to work with Flex, Adobe would really like you to work in their proprietary system in Flash Builder. This can either mean the Flash Builder plugin in eclipse, or the standalone Flash Builder (built off of eclipse). If you are in Flash builder, the 'Flex' item will be in that menu.

If you don't want to use Flash Builder, there are other ways, and they are more complex. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444914/can-i-use-flex-without-flex-builder) for examples.